# Python 2/Python 3: pip freeze vs help("modules")

Tags: python, pip, python-idle

This is a two-part question on module access.

Since Py2/Py3 are separate installations, installed modules live independently on our machines. Which one is the to-go option, installing new modules in both the Py2 and Py3 folder or updating Py3 only? Also, where does `pip install` default?

The second question regards library access through IDLE. Calling BOTH `pip freeze` and `pip3 freeze`, tensorflow shows up as regularly listed. However, `help("modules")` reveals that tensorflow is not installed. Although I don't use IDLE, I generally wonder how this is synchronized with the Python installations on our machines. In other words, I wonder how it can be that `help("modules")` outputs such that neither the Py2 nor the Py3 installation is reflected. [image]

Comment: To manage the dependencies for your projects you can create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) per project. They will have their own Python interpreter version and installed libraries then.

Answer (score 0):

After installing python 2 or python 3 in your machine, you should create a virtual environment for each project of python. This is not mandatory but is a accepted best practice and helps to segregate the dependencies of each project.

If you are not creating virtual environment, `pip install` installs all your dependencies to the `site-packages` folder present inside the python folder created during installation at the system level.

If you create a virtual environment and also activate it then `pip install` will install all your dependencies into the `site-packages` folder present inside the virtual environment folder of the project.

The command to create virtual environment is to go to your project folder in the terminal and then fire the following command:

```
python -m venv <name_of_virtual_env_folder>
```

To activate the virtual environment use the following command:

```
source <name_of_virtual_env_folder>/bin/activate (For Linux machines)
```

and

```
<name_of_virtual_env_folder>/Scripts/activate (For Windows machines)
```

Now coming to second question. help("modules") shows all the modules present and not the packages installed. If you have confusion between inbuilt python modules and python packages, please google to get it cleared.